# How to find hooks being called by a Drupal page?

Tags: hooks

I am looking at module code, and this is one of my first time working with Drupal modules. How can I find which hooks are being called by the page that I am working on at the moment? I saw this [suggestion](https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/drupal-exposed), but I don't want to hack core like it suggests. I think I might be able to do it with the devel module, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [hook_module_implements_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) and do the drupal set message in here. You'll need to use a FAKE cache for the cache_bootstrap bin.

In your settings.php

```
if (!class_exists('DrupalFakeCache')) {
  $conf['cache_backends'][] = 'includes/cache-install.inc';
}
$conf['cache_class_cache_bootstrap'] = 'DrupalFakeCache';
```

I will say that hacking core in this case is the preferred way to do this. The person who wrote that linked article is a core maintainer; so they know what there talking about. Using hook_module_implements_alter with a fake cache backend will only make this fire on the first run of that hook. Additional calls to the hook will not be caught due to the static cache. Not using the static cache would require hacking core in this case.